# Matplotlib namespace issues?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, colors, namespaces, colormap

I have a question regarding the Matplotlib.pyplot and namespaces.
See the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm

x=np.linspace(0,1,28)
color=iter(cm.gist_rainbow_r(np.linspace(0,1,28)))
plt.clf()
for s in range(28):
    c=next(color)
    plt.plot(x,x*s, c=c)

plt.show()
```

The idea was to have the plots in different colors of the rainbow map.
Now what happens is that on first execution it works, but then things are getting weird.
On several consecutive executions the map is stopped being used and instead of that the default map is used.

I see that the problem may lie within the "c=c" in the plot function, but I have played around with different namings "c", "color", .... and could not find the systematic of the issue here.

Can someone reproduce the problem and (try the code at least 5 times or so consecutively) is able to explain, what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: this works fine for me. Could you perhaps upload an image showing where the problem is?

Comment: Sorry; I forgot to state the versions I am using. It is Python 3.4.1 and matplotlib 1.4.3.  Also; I just tried to reproduce it on a friend's computer (matplotlib 1.4.0.r...), and it did not work. Or better: the script behaved as expected.

Comment: @ tom: I believe that it works for you, as I could not reproduce it on the other machine. However; I do not need to upload an image of it failing, as I can explain it. From time to time it appears that within the plot the c parameter is not transferred properly, as the diagram is plotted with the default colors (repeating after a few). I even have tried to provide a constant rgba-tuple to the plot function like: "..., c=[0.0, 0.7, 0.2, 1.0]..". And then I had the same problem. Sometimes all lines did have the same color, and sometimes not. I really do not understand, what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue with mpl + python3.4+ that has been fixed in mpl v1.5+.

Many of the style parameters have multiple aliases (ex `'c'` vs `'color'`) which mpl was not merging properly and the artists were essentially getting told two different colors which internally means there is a dictionary with both `'c'` and `'color'` in it.

In python 3.4+ process-to-process order of iteration of dictionaries is random by default due to the seed for the underlying hash table being randomized (this was to prevent a possible DOS attack based on intentional hash table collisions).  In older versions of python it so happened that the user supplied color always came later in the iteration order so things coincidentally worked.

The simple work around (iirc) is to use `plot(x, y, color=c)` or update to mpl 1.5.1.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.